# angularjs custom directive repeat attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a requirement to add an attribute to every element which is the inverse of ngShow (for screen readers). I am trying to come up with custom directive to achieve the same and avoid repitition such as

```
<div id="1" ng-show="myform.somecondition" aria-disabled="!myform.somecondition">
```

My approach is the following

```
<div id="1" ng-show="myform.somecondition" ng-aria>


myapp.directive('ngAria', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false, 
terminal: true, //this setting is important to stop loop
priority: 1000, //this setting is important to make sure it executes before other directives
compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
  element.removeAttr("ng-aria");
  element.attr('aria-disabled', !attrs.ngShow);
  return {
    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  },
    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  
      $compile(iElement)(scope);
    }
  };
}
 };
});
```

When the page is rendered, the element is rendered correctly. However on subsequent changes to the conditional element (myform.somecondition), the aria-disabled is not getting updated. Please suggest how to address the issue. Thanks.

Comment: The element.attr should look like `element.attr('aria-disabled','!' + attrs.ngShow);`. Can you try.

Comment: @Chandermani sorry it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your directive, including removing `terminal: true`, which is contributing to the problem you've expressed.

Inside of a $watch on the local scope, use `$eval` to evaluate the expression contained in `ng-show` and negate it for the value of `aria-disabled`:

```
.directive('ngAria', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false, 
    priority: 1000, 
    link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {  
      elem.removeAttr("ng-aria");
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngShow, function(){
        elem.attr('aria-disabled', !scope.$eval(attrs.ngShow));  
      });
    }
 };
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/uW7yBsTYYlrh8dLyi2WS?p=preview)